# How to set time for capturing video using python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a code that capture video from camera from github https://gist.github.com/keithweaver/4b16d3f05456171c1af1f1300ebd0f12#file-save-video-w-opencv-py.

But how to set time limit to this capture?.I want to capture multiple videos continuously with duration say 3 minutes without any frame drops.

I m kind of new to programming can anyone help with the code. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like that:

1. `startTime = time.time()`
2. `timeElapsed = startTime - time.time()` in seconds
3. `secElapsed = int(timeElapsed)`
4. Stop the program when `while(secElapsed < 100)`

Example of the code, it should look like that:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

# The duration in seconds of the video captured
capture_duration = 10

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

start_time = time.time()
while( int(time.time() - start_time) < capture_duration ):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        out.write(frame)
         cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `moviepy`.
Set `start` and `end` durations in terms of seconds. Say, you want to capture subclip, starting from second minute, (e.g. start=120), you want to record for 5 minutes. (5minutes=300seconds). Here is how to do it:

```
from moviepy import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip("/path/to/video.mp4")
starting_point = 120  # start at second minute
end_point = 420  # record for 300 seconds (120+300)
subclip = clip.subclip(starting_point, end_point)
subclip.write_videofile("/path/to/new/video.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

From what @Ali Yilmaz stated, that might be a bit outdated. It works this way on a 32-bit arm processor with Debian Buster with kernel 4.19.x and python3.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip("/path/to/yourfile.mp4")

start = 10 # start at 10 seconds
end   = 25 # plays for 15 seconds and ends at 25 seconds

subclip = clip.subclip(start, end)
subclip.write_videofile("/path/to/yournewfile.mp4")
```

I think the only difference in my moviepy setup and Ali's set up was the fact that in two years things changed with moviepy distributions and installations.